# $K_{n-1}-K_n = \frac{\pi}{4n^2}$ with $K_n = \frac{\pi \int_{0}^{\pi/2} t^2\left(\cos t\right)^{2n}dt}{2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\cos t\right)^{2n}dt}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $I_n$, $J_n$ and $K_n$ be the three sequences
$$
I_n = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\cos t\right)^{2n}\text{d}t, \ J_n = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} t^2\left(\cos t\right)^{2n}\text{d}t\text{ and }K_n = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{J_n}{I_n}.
$$

I've shown that
$$I_n = n\left(2n-1\right)J_{n-1} - 2n^2 J_n$$
and my goal is to show that
$$
K_{n-1} - K_n = \frac{\pi}{4n^2}.
$$

I know that I could plug in the explicit expression of $I_n = \frac{\left(2n\right) !}{4^n\left(n!\right)^2}\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I'm searching for a way of proving the relation over $K_n$ **without using the explicit relation for $I_n$.**

What I have tried is
\begin{align}
\frac{4n^2}{\pi}\left(K_{n-1}-K_n\right) &= 2n^2\left(\frac{J_{n-1}}{I_{n-1}} - \frac{J_{n}}{I_{n}}\right)\\
& = \frac{ 2n^2 J_{n-1}}{I_{n-1}} -\frac{ 2n^2 J_n}{I_n}\\
& = 1+\frac{2n^2 J_{n-1} - 2n^2 J_{n-1}I_{n-1} + n I_{n-1} J_{n-1}}{I_n I_{n-1}}
\end{align}

Well, I hoped I could make some terms disappear to leave only $1$ but I did not succeed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need one more relation connecting $(J_n)$ and $(I_n)$ to get further, because sole $I_n = n\left(2n-1\right)J_{n-1} - 2n^2 J_n$ is not equivalent to your goal.

Comment: Something like $I_n = \frac{n+1}{n+2} I_{n-1}$ would be sufficient ?

Comment: Are you sure you've done all right? $I_n = n\left(2n-1\right)J_{n-1} - 2n^2 J_n$ and $I_n = \frac{n+1}{n+2} I_{n-1}$ lead to $K_n=K_{n-1} \frac{2n^2+3n-2}{2n^2+2n}-\frac{\pi}{4n^2}$ which contradicts to your goal.

Comment: Ah, yes it's $I_n=\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-1}$, but how do you use it to obtain the expression you gave me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you already found $$\frac{J_n}{I_n}=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\frac{J_{n-1}}{I_n}-\frac{1}{2n^2} \, .$$
You similarly find $$I_n=\frac{2n-1}{2n} \, I_{n-1}$$
i.e. $$\frac{J_n}{I_n}=\frac{J_{n-1}}{I_{n-1}} - \frac{1}{2n^2}\,,$$
from which your objective follows.

Answer (score 0):

We can even do more since
$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\cos ^{2 n}(t)\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \,\,\Gamma (n+1)}$$
For
$$J_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}t^2\,\cos ^{2 n}(t)\,dt$$ we need to use the linearization of even powers of the cosine function (*this is the part you need to work*)
$$\cos^{2n}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\, \cos(2mt)$$ and
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}t^2\,\cos (2 mt)\,dt=(-1)^m\,\frac{\pi  }{4 m^2}$$

This gives
$$K_n=\frac \pi 2 \,\,\frac{J_n}{I_n}=\frac {\pi^3}{24}-\frac \pi 4\,H_n^{(2)}$$ where appear the generalized harmonic numbers
$$ H_n^{(2)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {k^2}$$ and this makes now the problem  more then simple if you take into account the above definition.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you should fill some details.

Comment: @Diger. I wrote that the key is the linearization of $\cos^{2n}(x)$ (simple and quite trivial) that I let to the user.

Comment: I guess so, but you could at least have added the $a_k$.